# azure functions integrations available with azure data lake

Tags: azure-functions, azure-data-lake, u-sql

I have some USQL scripts that will generate files:

```
@output=
EXTRACT..
OUTPUT @output
TO "/myFirstFunction_{myId}.txt"
USING Outputters.Tsv();
```

For every generation of one of these files: `/myFirstFunction_{myId}.txt` I would like to trigger an Azure Function.

**How do we trigger an Azure Function from data lake?**

Answer (score 1):

There isn’t a trigger specifically for data lake - so I would recommend using the [event grid integration](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/event-driven-analytics-with-azure-data-lake-storage-gen2/) to fire an event to a function to trigger which can then pull the contents or act as needed

Comment: you are saying if i want to trigger a stored procedure in data lake, i could fire an event through event grid, and that has the ability to trigger the sproc? could you show an example or a link? thank you so much

Comment: btw have you seen this library? https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-datalake-extension it looks pretty good but doesnt seem to be too popular

Comment: Saying you should be a able to trigger a function for each one of those files generated using that new event grid feature. Would look very similar to this sample. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/resize-images-on-storage-blob-upload-event?tabs=dotnet

Comment: thanks so much. how do i programmatically trigger a sproc that is in data lake?

Comment: you are saying that the data lake can simply be treated as a storage account right? in regards to events being fired from it?

Comment: Correct. Assume some data lake SDK that maybe could fire sproc but meant more like storage

Comment: you cant have integration with gen1